# What is the correct tone for 压 in 高压电 (high voltage) and 低压电 (low voltage)?

Tags: pronunciation, tones

In the following signs, we have 高压电 (high voltage) and 低压电 (low voltage).  [Chinese Converter](https://www.chineseconverter.com/en/convert/chinese-to-pinyin) gives the pinyin: gāo yā diàn and dī yā diàn (this has been wrong in the past).  However, [Dict.cn](http://dict.cn/%E5%8E%8B) and [WrittenChinese.com](https://dictionary.writtenchinese.com/worddetail/ya/6667/1/1) assign 压 two possible tones: yā (first tone) or yà (fourth tone).  So I don't know which is correct.

**Question**: What is the correct tone for 压 in 高压电 and 低压电?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The 1st tone is correct. `压` with the 4th tone is used for very specified case.

Comment: ＂现代汉语词典＂ yà  only in ［压板］（方）跷跷板 ［压根儿］根本；从来（多用于否定句）：他全忘了，好像～没有这回事。bkrs：yàbǎn〈方〉跷跷板。 seesaw； teeterboard； teetertotter ； 
yàbǎn[seasaw] 翘板 yà bǎn vise jaw
press board (machine)see-saw  iciba（also bkrs）
压板 [yā bǎn] platen； clamp； pressplate； flat

Comment: From bing, 电压: voltage, electric tension, electric pressure. It seems that 电压 is translated from **electric pressure**, so 高压电 literally means **high pressure electric**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, both tones are possible. In different rigon in China, people have different pronunciation of the same word. However, yā is the official pronunciation of "压". And it used in more scene than yà.

Answer (score 1):

According to Chinese daily habits,Chinese prefer the first tone and in many formal situations,like CCTV, the hoster speaks the first tone.But if you want to speak the fourth tone,they can also understand your idea.So you don't care whether the correct tone is first tone  or not (if you're talking with Chinese ).But if you're preparing for exam,I think you should choose the first tone.